# In MAAS 1.9.1, what do I do to fix the error "Node must be connected to a network"?

Tags: maas

Just upgraded to MAAS 1.9.1 from 1.8.something, and struggling with the networking setup.

My MAAS nodes are on a subnet that already has a non-MAAS DHCP server.  I don't want MAAS to manage or assign any IP addresses itself; I only want it to deploy and release nodes, and to allow each node to pick up its IP from the non-MAAS DHCP server.  How do I do that?

(I also don't want any VLANs or bond interfaces.)

Answer (score 0):

Visit the node details page for the node that is reporting "Node must be connected to a network".

On that page select the subnet you want the interface to DHCP from and then select "DHCP" in the IP assignment section.

[Screenshot of networking Section with DHCP set on interface.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZGIA.png)